# dpkg cannot install phpMyAdmin and MySQL (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to install phpMyAdmin, but I constantly get errors.

When I type this in the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

The following message appears:

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.0 (5.0.45-1ubuntu3) ...
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                     [OK]
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                     [FAIL]
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.0 (--configure):
 subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.0; however:
  Package mysql-server 5.0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encounter while processing:
 mysql-server-5.0
 mysql-server
```

I also attempt to access MySQL through the console by typing: `mysql`

This error appears:

```
ERROR (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

This occurred ever I tried to install phpMyAdmin or accessing my `libapache`. Does anyone know how to resolve these problems?

Answer (score 2):

The installer error is related to the `mysql-server-5.0` package. You probably should do an `apt-get purge mysql-server-5.0` and then try reinstalling it.  Once that has been installed, try and install phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

You might also be able to get away with

```
dpkg --configure mysql-server-5.0
```

since 'mysql-server' is a meta package.